Why the compiler complain about `std::enable_if<is_allowed_type<T>::value>::type*=nullptr`?
I can't figure out why
std::enable_if<is_allowed_type<T>::value>::type*=nullptr
does not work, while
std::enable_if<is_allowed_type<T>::value>::type* =nullptr
works well.
The difference is just a blank space. Does the *= is treated as an operator?
Here is the code snippet:
#include <stdint.h>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
class is_allowed_type:public std::false_type{};

template<>
class is_allowed_type<uint8_t>:public std::true_type{};

template<>
class is_allowed_type<uint16_t>:public std::true_type{};

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<is_allowed_type<T>::value>::type foo(T val){}

template<class T, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_allowed_type<T>::value>::type>
void goo(T val){}

template<class T>
void koo(T val, typename std::enable_if<is_allowed_type<T>::value>::type*=nullptr){}

template<class T>
void hoo(T val, typename std::enable_if<is_allowed_type<T>::value>::type* = nullptr){}

int main() {
    unsigned char val{'0'};
    uint16_t num{0};
    foo(val);  //works;
    foo(num);  //works;
    //foo(6);    //not compile as expected
    //foo(3.14); //not compile as expected 
    return 0;
}

Here is what the compiler complains:
<source>:20:73: error: expected ')'
   20 | void koo(T val, typename std::enable_if<is_allowed_type<T>::value>::type*=nullptr){}
      |                                                                         ^
<source>:20:9: note: to match this '('
   20 | void koo(T val, typename std::enable_if<is_allowed_type<T>::value>::type*=nullptr){}
      |         ^
1 error generated.

I did a simple test to verify my guess which the compiler complies again.

void foo1(int*=nullptr){}
void foo2(int* =nullptr){}

int main() {
    return 0;
}

I really curious about the reason lies behind it.

"Does the *= is treated as an operator?" Yes.

@cpplearner Why *= is treated as an operator, other than type* = nullptr?

Because unsigned int a{1}; a *= 5; should work. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic. It should apply to all integral types.

If there is no space, then it is the operator. This decision is made before the compiler realizes that *= makes no sense there. There is a similar problem with >> in templates, and it took decades to fix.

This is called maximal munch princinple and I've explained it in here. See example 2 and example 3 in that answer of the dupe: What is the difference between auto&& y = x and auto& &y= x in modern C++?

i += 2 ,  j -= 3,  k %= 4 ,  type *= 5 ...

Basically the same reason int & *i = 4; gives error in example 2 of the dupe.

Some of us remember when you had to use > > to terminate a nested template, because >> was only the shift operator. Lucklily, fixed by now,


Does the *= is treated as an operator?

Yes. This is called the "maximal munch" rule.
During compilation, the longest match is consumed to form a token. Since *= is a valid token, it is taken as a whole, instead of two separate tokens * and =.
In C++, a "token" is one of: identifier, keyword, (string/character/numerical/user-defined) literal, operator or punctuator.
Thus, the identifier type is a token, the operator *= is a token, the operators * and = are two tokens if separated (but each is shorter than *=), and the string type* is not a token.

but type* is as long as *=, they are both two tokens.

It's not "maximum munch" but "maximal munch"

*= is not two tokens. It is one token. Just like how a/*b is not a divided by *b but a followed by the start of a comment.
